# How to find the count of the maximum pair of a window

Tags: algorithm, sliding-window

Today I got an interview question about finding the maximum pair window but I felt like I could solve it more efficient. I was wondering if theres any way to solve it more efficiently.

```
Input: nums = [1,3,-1,-3,5,3,6,7], k = 3, n = 7
Output: 3
Explanation: 
Window position                Max
---------------               -----
[1  3  -1] -3  5  3  6  7       4 (1,3) < 7 false
 1 [3  -1  -3] 5  3  6  7       2 (3, -1) < 7 false
 1  3 [-1  -3  5] 3  6  7       4 (5, -1) < 7 false
 1  3  -1 [-3  5  3] 6  7       8 (5,3) > 7 true
 1  3  -1  -3 [5  3  6] 7       11 (6,5) > 7 true
 1  3  -1  -3  5 [3  6  7]      13 (6,7) > 7 true
```

just solved it by getting the subarray -> sorting then getting the last 2 element but I think theres a more efficient solution?

Comment: What is the "maximum pair window"?

Comment: What is that ```n=7``` there ?

Comment: To the extent we can have O(1) range minimum queries (and there are many such methods), we could find the second smallest in O(1) as well, by querying each of the remaining sections in the interval around the minimum we just found. The question is whether there may be an online O(n) algorithm.